# How can I make a curved graph in Tikz and vertical lines from the x-axis to that graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, vertical, addlines

I am basically trying to make this figure in Tikz only better, but I can't figure out how to make the vertical lines from the x-axis to the graphs M(x). The function is M(x)=−1/2·q·x^2+1/2·q·L·x, where the values of q and L doesn't matter in the first place.

(The figure is made in Maple 2018. It hints at the mistakes made in the vertical lines.)

[image: A curve with the maximum point at Mmax]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What have you tried so far? Please add your attempt as a compilable document to the question so that others can use it as a base.

Comment: Use a `ycomb` plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very 'hacky' solution, and I'm sure some people will be able to give you a more elegant answer, but this definitely works!

I also like it because it's been a very broadly applicable technique for me (especially using intersections).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[<->] (0,6) node[above]{M}--(0,0)--(9,0)node[right]{L};
    \draw[name path = C] (0,0) .. controls (3,6) and (5,6) .. (8,0) node[pos = 0.5, above] {$M_{max} = \dfrac{1}{8} \cdot q \cdot L^2$};

    \foreach \i in {0,0.5,...,8}{
        \draw[draw opacity = 0, name path = L] (\i,0)--(\i,6);
        \draw [name intersections ={of = L and C}] let \p1 = (intersection-1) in (\x1,\y1)--(\x1,0);
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

PS: If you need the curve to look differently, just edit the code for `\draw[name path = C]...`. For instance, by changing it to:

```
\draw[name path = C] (0,0) .. controls (2,4) and (6,4) .. (8,0) node[pos = 0.5, above] {$M_{max} = \dfrac{1}{8} \cdot q \cdot L^2$};
```

you get this (which is closer to your original image). I illustrated this just in case you wanted to see a sample of how to draw curves. :)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

As I mention in a comment, a `ycomb` plot can be used for this. Here are two examples, the first a modified version of [marmot's code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459337), the second a more verbose (and probably more complicated than it needs to be) version using `pgfplots`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    M(\x) = 4-(\x-4)*(\x-4)/4;
  }
]
\draw[latex-latex] (0,6) node[left] {$\mathbf{M}$} |- (8.5,0) node[below]
{$\mathbf{L}$};
  \draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:8,smooth] ({\x},{M(\x)});
  \draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:8,ycomb] ({\x},{M(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  declare function={
    t = 2;
    mid = 5;
    d=4.5;
    M(\x) = -(\x-mid)^2*(t/d^2) + t;
  },
  axis lines=middle,
  xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
  ylabel=$M$, xlabel=$L$,
  enlarge x limits,
  enlarge y limits={value=0.5,upper},
  domain=mid-d:mid+d
]

\addplot [thick] {M(x)} node[midway, above] {$M_{\max} = \frac{1}{8} qL$};
\addplot [ycomb, samples=15] {M(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one more possibility: use a `pattern`. And if you use `\clip`, as [suggested by @nidhin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/459333/121799), I'd use a grid rather than a foreach loop. In fact, if you use `\foreach`, since the function is known, you do not need `\clip`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (0,6) node[left] {$\boldsymbol{M}$} |- (8.5,0) node[below]
{$\boldsymbol{L}$};
\draw[thick,pattern=vertical lines] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:8,smooth] ({\x},{4-(\x-4)*(\x-4)/4});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex] (0,6) node[left] {$\boldsymbol{M}$} |- (8.5,0) node[below]
{$\boldsymbol{L}$};
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:8,smooth] ({\x},{4-(\x-4)*(\x-4)/4});
\clip plot[variable=\x,domain=0:8,smooth] ({\x},{4-(\x-4)*(\x-4)/4});
\draw (0,0) grid[xstep=1cm,ystep=6cm] (8,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Using `clip`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \draw(4,5) node {$M_{max} = \dfrac18 \cdot q \cdot L^2$};
    \draw[<->] (0,6) node[above]{M}--(0,0)--(9,0)node[right]{L};
    \draw[clip] (0,0) .. controls (3,6) and (5,6) .. (8,0) --cycle;
    \foreach \i in {0,0.5,...,8}
    \draw (\i,0) -- ++ (0,10);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]